# Can't log in to forums.ageofempires.com

Tags: age-of-empires

When I try to log in to [forums.ageofempires.com](https://forums.ageofempires.com/), I get a popup box in which I can choose to log in with my Steam account or with my Xbox Live account, of which I choose to log in with my Steam account.

I'm then redirected to steamcommunity.com and I get to press in a button that says "Sign In" under a square that identifies my Steam account.

Once that's done, I'm taken back to forums.ageofempires.com, which displays a popup box with the text "Welcome! Let's create your account". I'm prompted for my email address, and then at the bottom of the box, there is a button that says "Create your account". However, when I press that button, I get an error message saying "Email has already been taken".

I guess this is from an account which I have already registered on this page. So, the question is, how can I log in with that account which I already have? Right now, I see no way to log in with that email address.